# Deploy secrets Gcloud run from pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy to gcp secrets stored as variables in azure devops.

But when I try the command

```
gcloud run deploy  --update-secrets=myvar=$(myvar)
```

as stated in the official documentation `gcloud run deploy  --update-secrets=[KEY=VALUE,…]` , it throws this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) No secret version specified for myvar. Use myvar:latest to reference the latest version. 
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

Given that the pipeline correctly recognizes `$(myvar)`. And given that changing `gcloud run deploy  --update-secrets=myvar:latest=$(myvar)`  won't give effects.

How should I release this secret?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thing that worked was running
`gcloud run deploy  --update-secrets = myvar=$(myvar):latest`

Documentation is available here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#command-line

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets are just indications that you can provide multiple values, separated by a comma.

So this should work:

```
gcloud run deploy  --update-secrets="myvar=$(myvar)"
```

Comment: Leaving the square bracket away, it throws the following error: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) No secret version specified for myvar. Use myvar:latest to reference the latest version.

Comment: Yet, if I add :latest to the string, it tells me to use myvar:latest:latest

Comment: Issue here is that maybe there is a different way to inject secrets from devops. They can't be variables, maybe?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml